# How to remove problematic control from visual studio 2008 toolbox?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I added an asp.net control to my project in visual studio 2008 after that any attempt to open the toolbox or to switch into design mode (aspx file) causes visual studio to freeze.

I've tried to reset visual studio enviroment settings.

**update:**
any other project without this control opens fine!

Comment: the tool back can take a while to open. How long did you wait until killing VS because it was frozen? 10sec? 10min? I have had the tool box take upwards of 1-2mins to open. By then again my computer is 4+ years old. =P

Answer (score 0):

What about

[Visual Studio Toolbox Manager](http://vstudiotoolbox.codeplex.com/)